# Array with several strings is concatenated

Tags: ruby

Array with more than one string separated with space produces array with one concatenated string. IMHO, it should raise syntax error. Is this behavior correct?

```
["1" "2" "3"]
#=> ["123"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with array. It is a feature of string literal. If you write string literals in quotes next to each other, it represents the string that is given by the concatenation.

Comment: Yes: `"1" "2" "3" => "123"`

Comment: Got it. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: I think the rationale goes back to C where you have the [same feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation). Yet, you cannot to something like `"error in " __FILE__ ":" __LINE__` which is valid in C.